# Need to split a string into substrings but can't use split

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I have a string that looks like this:

> 123.45.67.890-1292 connected to EDS via 10.98.765.432-4300.

I need to split it like so:

```
   "123.45.67.890-1292 connected to EDS via 10.98.765.432-4300."
    -----+------- --+-              -+-     -----+------- --+-
         |          |                |           |          |
  ClientIP          |      ServiceName      HostIP          |
                    |                                       |
        ClientSession                             HostSession
```

I'm converting the code from vbscript that has a lot of complex InStr methods. Was wondering if there was a way to do this using a regEx.

Comment: I think writing that nice ascii graphics took longer than it would have taken you to learn enough about regular expressions to make this happen. :)

Comment: are "connected to" and "via" present in every case?

Comment: answer: yes there is. OT: @IAbstractDownvoteFactory - awesome screen name

Comment: Why can't you use split, and why is RegEx the answer?  If you're doing this at large scale, consider http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/01/regex-performance.html

Comment: Why can't you use split? Seems like splitting on space and getting them from their indexes would be easy.

Comment: ASCII was inherited from the VBScript, but figured it would help you guys out. I was thinking of using split, but then wondered if there was a way to do this using RegEx. Now I know that there is....it just isn't as easy, clean, or intuitive as using split.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why can't you use split? Using regular expression for single task is inappropriate:

```
([^\-]+)\-(\S+)\s+connected\s+to\s+(\S+)\s+via\s+([^\-]+)\-(\S+)\.
```

C# code implementation (regular expression):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    String input = "123.45.67.890-1292 connected to EDS via 10.98.765.432-4300.";
    String pattern = @"([^\-]+)\-(\S+)\s+connected\s+to\s+(\S+)\s+via\s+([^\-]+)\-(\S+)\.";

    Match match = Regex.Match(input, pattern);

    if (match.Success)
    {
        foreach (var group in match.Groups)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(group);
        }
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

C# code implementation (splitting):

```
public class DTO
{
    public string ClientIP { get; set; }
    public string ClientSession { get; set; }
    public string ServiceName { get; set; }
    public string HostIP { get; set; }
    public string HostSession { get; set; }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    String input = "123.45.67.890-1292 connected to EDS via 10.98.765.432-4300.";
    String[] splits = input.Split(new char[] { ' ' });

    DTO obj = new DTO();

    for (int i = 0; i < splits.Length; ++i) 
    {
        switch (i) 
        {
            // connected
            case 1:
            // to
            case 2:
            // via 
            case 4:
                {
                    break;
                }

            // 123.45.67.890-1292
            case 0:
                {

                    obj.ClientIP = splits[i].Split(new char[] { '-' })[0];
                    obj.ClientSession = splits[i].Split(new char[] { '-' })[1];

                    break;
                }

            // EDS
            case 3:
                {
                    obj.ServiceName = splits[i];
                    break;
                }

            // 10.98.765.432-4300.
            case 5:
                {
                    obj.HostIP = splits[i].Split(new char[] { '-' })[0];
                    obj.HostSession = splits[i].Split(new char[] { '-' })[1];

                    break;
                }

        }

    }

    Console.ReadKey();  
}
```

Comment: thanks for the full code. That was a better solution then I had.

Answer (score 8):

`(\d{,3}\.\d{,3}\.\d{,3}\.\d{,3})-(\d+) connected to ([A-Z]+) via (\d{,3}\.\d{,3}\.\d{,3}\.\d{,3})-(\d+)\.`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a RegExp to match/capture that:

```
([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)-([0-9]+) connected to ([a-zA-Z]+) via ([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)-([0-9]+)
```

implementation:

```
        string pat = @"([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)-([0-9]+) connected to ([a-zA-Z]+) via ([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)-([0-9]+)";
        Regex r = new Regex(pat, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        Match match = r.Match("123.45.67.890-1292 connected to EDS via 10.98.765.432-4300.");

        foreach (var str in match.Groups)
            Console.WriteLine(str);
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Thanks. Decided to go the split route. It's just slightly cleaner for my needs.

Answer (score 1):

`(?<ClientIP>\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)-(?<ClientSession>\d+) connected to (?<ServiceName>.*?) via (?<HostIP>\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)-(?<HostSession>\d+)\.`

Answer (score 1):

Since I don't see why you rule out String.Split() :

```
var parts = test.Split(new string[] {" connected to ", " via "},
      StringSplitOptions.None);
```

gives you

```
123.45.67.890-1292
EDS
10.98.765.432-4300
```

breaking of the `-####` session parts would take 1 extra step, also possible with Split().

Or maybe easier:

```
 var parts = test.Split(' ', '-');
```

and use parts 0, 1, 4, 6, 7

Comment: This is what I was thinking but don't you lose the extra benefit that RegEx also validates that its an IP address-session